# How to stop in FireBug when submit button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I want to stop (break) in the first function called whenever a submit button is pressed in a form.  How can I set a break-point for this in Firebug?

I know how to stop in any line in a function.  But in one case I don't know which function is getting called upon pressing "submit" button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your real problem is that you don't know which function is being called (once you know that you can use breakpoints).

Try enabling the 'Net' tab, select 'All' and click 'Persist'. This will show you a list of functions that are being called. Hit the submit button and expand the first function in the list. This is the first function being called after submitting.

Comment: I'm trying to open a new tab for this url:http://www.ap.bsnl.co.in/1991/CscsubViewYes.asp for each city. I've done as you said. But when I press submit it's showing +GET customerselection.asp underneath Welcome to APTelecom.    I don't see the first function getting called. Also after I press submit, it's showing results from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Open Firebug, go to the script tab and select the script you want. I think you can either click the number of the line (on the left), or on the right hand panel you can create "breakpoints" which will stop the script at the points you designate.

Comment: and to know which function is getting called...check out the function name in submit button call in your mark-up

Comment: Could be a bit difficult if he doesn't know which function is being called :)

Comment: Alex I don't know which function is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Type this into the Firebug console - it will stop any form on that page from submitting and display the id. You will need to include jquery with the page if you haven't already.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  console.log(this.id);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm want to use jquery to automaticaly open one tab for each city name : http://www.ap.bsnl.co.in/1991/customerselection.asp. I'm using JQuerify addon to attach jquery. But if I give $("p") or $("form") after reload in the console it's giving "null" for all.

Comment: You can just include it using the google CDN by adding the following `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js` to the a pair of script tags in the head of your document